# Using a cell value for a named range from another workbook in vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to write a vlookup that would take the contents of a cell as the named range in which to search the vlookup in another workbook.
Something like:

where e3 = "NamedRange" or something.

=VLOOKUP($J$1,INDIRECT("filename!"& E3),3)

Well it gives a !REF error as one would expect.

How does one properly do this?
Thanks

Comment: Is the other workbook open?

Comment: Normally no but it is for testing.  The only thing that really changes is when it closes the filename includes it's path.

Comment: Realize the `INDIRECT` which will need to be used, does not work with closed workbooks.

Comment: The next thing that one should ask, is the named range, worksheet or workbook scope.  The will require different strings on the filename.

Comment: Workbook scope.  I wasn't planning on having the 2nd workbook open but that's not a deal breaker.

Comment: it should be `INDIRECT("'filename'!"& E3)`

Comment: Personally I would create a Worksheet_Change Event that rewrites the VLOOKUP  with the correct reference without INDIRECT so the workbook can remain closed.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. Might do that in v2 :)  But the solution works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @ScottCraner it works out.

`INDIRECT("'filename'!"& E3)`
I just had an issue with `[]` being added in by Excel and I had to remove them.